# 'Expression Expected' when loading JSON file in a variable

Tags: python, json

I'm storing a dictionary on a JSON file so I can easily access and change the data between sessions.  This is how I'm trying to load the file into a variable, but after "pc_data = " I'm getting 'Expression Expected' from PyCharm.  How am I able to load the file into a variable and then continue the function after variable assignment?  Code below:

```
pc_data = with open(lib_dir+'player_characters.txt', 'r') as json_data:
    json.load(json_data)
    yield json_data
```

Comment: Drop the `pc_data =`. Also, this should be within a function as you are using `yield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `with` is incorrect. `with` does not return a value, so you cannot assign it. 
Try this:

```
with open(lib_dir+'player_characters.txt', 'r') as json_data:
    pc_data = json.load(json_data)
    yield pc_data  # <- I'm guessing you want to yield parsed json here?
```